# Where is the FIReventNames.h file listing the various event classes for Google Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

We want to log an event in Google Firebase like we do in Yahoo Flurry:

> [Flurry logEvent:@"Stats page visited"];

How?

Google Firebase documentation claims that to find "[suggested events see the FIReventNames.h header file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events#add_analytics_to_your_app_numbered)" but we are unable to find this file.

Where do we find this file?

- Searching the project in Xcode - we don't see it even though we have
  installed the POD files for Firebase/Analytics.
- Search Google and there is [essentially nothing](https://www.google.com/search?q=FIReventNames.h&oq=FIReventNames.h&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61.550j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). There are just *five* results. Not five pages. Five *results*.  Three of those results are duplicates of the page we linked above.
- If you look at the iOS Samples, they contribute nothing additional. Google's sample code gives three examples for logging Firebase events and they are the exact same examples as on the page we referenced above. None seem to show what we are trying to do above.

We seem unable to find any of the other classes for the various event types.

Where do we find the suggested Firebase analytic event logging classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIREventNames.h can be found in Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.Framework/Headers

To log that event with Firebase Analytics, first :

```
@import FirebaseAnalytics;
```

then issue the following call :

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"stats_page_visited" parameters:nil];
```

Comment: Is @import FirebaseAnalytics; the correct syntax or #import <FirebaseAnalytics/FIRAnalytics.h>? There is some swizzling that Google built so the import work in a smart way. Does that still work both ways?

Comment: @import FirebaseAnalytics; is correct if you're using modules.